# Codeigniter : how can i get user data by user_id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm still very new to this codeigniter. So i have a tables in my database called `users` table and `t_lowongan` table. The `t_lowongan` table have `user_id` field as a foreign key for the `id_user` in the `users` table. So when the user login and create a job posting, the `user_id` will be filled by the `id_user` from that user. I want to get the user data so that this user know which job posting that he has created by that user, but the data isn't showing, how can i fix it??

The Controller Lowongan :

```
public function lowongan()
    {
        $this_id = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
        $data['t_lowongan'] = $this->db->get_where('t_lowongan', ['user_id', $this_id])->result();
        $this->load-view('lowongan', $data);
    }
```

Comment: [I'm still very new to this codeigniter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422604/2943403)

Comment: The model layer is responsible for sourcing data from the database.  We should never see `get_where()` called from a controller.  Model methods should always be ignorant of their source data.  The controller should pass the session data to the model for optimal utility.  In other words, we should never see session data accessed directly from the model.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to debugging isn't quite right here. Firstly, you must understand that the database object's `result()` method returns an array of row objects in the form of `$row->field` (or in your case, `$row->user_id`). On the other hand, the database object's `result_array()` method returns an array of arrays (in your case, $row['user_id']). Since you've used the former, I hope you've dealt with those row objects accordingly in the `lowongan` view which you then show. Failure to do so might result in the problem you've described in the question.

Assuming you've taken care of the view, the second thing to do then is to place an `error_log()` statement and see what value it's returning. You can place something like this just after the `get_where()` statement and then observe your HTTP server logs what value it's getting:

```
error_log("THE RESULT IS: " . print_r($data, true));
```

Depending on whether or not this is printing the correct value, you can then further troubleshoot where exactly the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You must create controller and model and call model from construct

constroller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class LowonganController extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model(array('m_lowongan'));
    }

    public function lowongan() {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
        $data['t_lowongan']  = $this->m_lowongan->get_user_by_id($id);
        $this->load-view('lowongan', $data);
    }
}
```

model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class M_Lowongan extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_user_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
        $query  = $this->db->get('your_table_name');
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cleaner to use `get_where()` in `get_user_by_id()` with declaring `$query`.

Answer (score -1):

So what i did is that. I create a function called get_data on my model

The model :

```
public function get_data($where, $table){
        return $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
    }
```

And in the controller i just do this :

The Controller :

```
public function lowongan()
    {
        $this_id = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
        $data['t_lowongan'] = $this->m_lowongan->get_data($where,'t_lowongan')->result();
        $this->load-view('lowongan', $data);
    }
```

And it works :D. But please let me know if this is like a wrong thing to do, Thank you :D